# Searching a string, output it to an array then delete it based on user input

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell

So I'm developing a simple Address book and its going well.
It uses a singular text file to store all its information.

At the minute i can searh the file for a specific string, not a problem.

I'm pretty sure i can get it to delete a string based on a users input, thats kind of easy but i thought for extra snazziness it would be
a neat idea if I could grab the output of the search term - a multi-line output say - and store each new line into an array, each assigned a number.
From there the user could specify they would like to delete the line based on their input.

So far this is the 'delete' script:

```
ADDRESSBOOK=~/Documents/Address-Book/add_data.txt

export ADDRESSBOOK

echo "=============================== Delete a Record ==============================="
echo "==============================================================================="
echo "============ Search A Record, then delete it! Type 'exit' to exit ============="

exit=0
search(){
    while [ $exit -ne 1 ]
    do

        echo "Find something for me to delete"
        echo -n "-----------------------> "

        read searchTerm
        if [ "$searchTerm" = "exit" ]
        then
            exit=1
        else

            searchOutput=$(grep $searchTerm*.$ $ADDRESSBOOK | sort)

            echo "$searchOutput"
        fi
    done

    exit 0
}

search
```

The address book automatically adds each record with /n so it displays each record on a new line anyway.

Is it possible to take the $searchRecord variable and pass that to an array?

And before I go wrapping my head around arrays, is this even the best approach to take for what I'm trying to do?

I am currently trying something along the lines of

```
if [ "$searchTerm" = "exit" ]
then 
    exit=1
else

    searchOutput=$(grep $searchTerm*.$ $ADDRESSBOOK | sort)
    echo {$searchOutput[*] '/n' }

fi
```

the '/n' is to TRY and get the records to each appear on a new line. Any advice guys?

Comment: I'd start by using `'\n'`, which is the proper representation of a new line in ascii.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    while  read -p 'Find something for me to delete> ' searchTerm
  [[ $searchTerm != 'exit' ]]   do readarray -t searchOutput < <(grep -i -w "$searchTerm" "$ADDRESSBOOK" | sort)



        if ((${#searchOutput[@]}>0)); then

        PS3="Select line to delete: "

            select line in "${searchOutput[@]}"; do

            [[ -z $line ]] && break

            line=$(fgrep -nx "$line" "$ADDRESSBOOK")



        sed -i ${line%%:*}d "$ADDRESSBOOK"

                echo "Deleting line" $line
            done
        elif [ $searchTerm = "exit" ]
        then 
        exit=1
            else
                echo "------------- Could Not Find > " $searchTerm
        exit=1
                fi
done
exit 0
}
```

Comment: This is really, really hard to read...consider having less random indentation when you paste code here as I'm sure some people are scared away by this, so you will probably get more help when your code is actually readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
l=$(grep $searchTerm $ADDRESSBOOK | \
    sort | { \
        n=0; \
        while read a; \
            do echo "searchOutput[$n]=\"$a\";" ; \
                n=$((n + 1)) ; \
            done; \
    })
eval $l

for line in "${searchOutput[@]}"
do
    echo $line
done
```